# Need an explaination for CTRL-A help doc , "... or alphabetic character"

Tags: help-system

```
CTRL-A          Add [count] to the number or alphabetic character at
            or after the cursor.

CTRL-X          Subtract [count] from the number or alphabetic
            character at or after the cursor.
```

What does it exactly mean "... or alphabetic character" in this help doc?

I have interpreted that it should increase/decrease the alphabetic character (ASCII value), even though it does not make sense though.
Anyway, it does not do anything to alphabetic charactor.
I appreciate any usage case with an example how to apply CTRL-A/CTRL-X to an alphabetic character.
Maybe, I am just confused the way it is written.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

"Alphabetical character" here stands for `[A-Za-z]` (see also `:h /\a`).

Make sure you've also seen `:h 'nrformats'` as `alpha` is not set by default.

Comment: thanks that wroks.